# populating a form in the same page according to an element clicked which the id is generated by jstl

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="3" step="1">
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin-right: 0% !important">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail book">
        <%                                              
        String TCurlI = "Def";
        String idImgIII = "null";
        pageContext.setAttribute("TCurlI", new String(TCurlI));
        pageContext.setAttribute("idImgIII", new String(idImgIII));
        %>
        <c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.livresTC[i].titre }">
            <c:set var="TCurlI" value="${sessionScope.livresTC[i].titre }"></c:set>
            <c:set var="idImgIII" value="${sessionScope.livresTC[i].numInventaire }"></c:set>
        </c:if>

        <img id="${idImgIII }" src="../media/Pics/<c:out value="${TCurlI }"></c:out>.jpg" alt="image" >

    </a>
</div>
```

this is how i get the id nd url for the img
and when i click the img i already have a js code that shows a panel

```
$('.book, .book *').click(function(event){//});
```

nd the session is filled with a method `ArrayList livres = db.getAllLivres();

```
public ArrayList<Livre> getAllLivres() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Livre> listeLivres = new ArrayList<Livre>();
    Livre livre; 
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Livre");
    while(rs.next()){
        /*(int numInventaire 1, 
         * String cote 2, 
         * String titre 3, 
         * int idAuteur 5, 
         * int idEdition 6, 
         * boolean disponible 4, 
         * String intituleNiveau 7, 
         * int idGenre 8),
         * Date dateAjout 9*/
        livre = new Livre(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6), rs.getBoolean(4), rs.getString(7), rs.getInt(8), rs.getDate(9));
        listeLivres.add(livre);
    }
    return listeLivres;
}
```

now i need to fill a form in the same jsp page with the rest of informations (cote, titre, ..) but which the numInventaire equals the img clicked id

Answer (score 0):

You can create another JSP file to render the form based on some request param like 'ID'.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
//retrieve 'livre' instance with the given ID
```

And in your javascript click listener, you can request that jsp file using AJAX and add the result to your popup innerHTML.

```
$('.book, .book *').click(function(event){
    //Get id from clicked item
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    //request the form jsp by id of livre
    $.ajax('formJspFile.jsp?id=' + id , {
        success:function(data){
            //add the form  jsp content to the popup div.
            $('#popupDiv').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```